# Configuring the browser used to display Gadfly plots in Julia

Tags: julia, gadfly

I am using Julia 0.4.5 on Windows 7.
When I invoke `Gadfly.plot`, Internet Explorer opens up to display the plot.

How can I configure Julia to use a browser of my choice (like Google Chrome) to display Gadfly plots?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems Gadfly use [this function](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/blob/master/src/Gadfly.jl#L1024) to open .html file:

```
function open_file(filename)
    if OS_NAME == :Darwin
        run(`open $(filename)`)
    elseif OS_NAME == :Linux || OS_NAME == :FreeBSD
        run(`xdg-open $(filename)`)
    elseif OS_NAME == :Windows
        run(`$(ENV["COMSPEC"]) /c start $(filename)`)
    else
        warn("Showing plots is not supported on OS $(string(OS_NAME))")
    end
end
```

So for Windows, you can write your alternative cmd.exe(maybe a .bat that checks if the argument is a .html, then launch chrome or pass to the true cmd.exe), and replace `ENV["COMSPEC"]`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @张实唯. I take this to mean that, at present, there is no way to configure Julia to use a browser of my choice. However, I could easily hack Gadfly.jl to do. Maybe I should make a pull request. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try:
Set Google chrome as default browser for your all .html or .htm files.

Comment: Julia seems pretty configurable. I am looking for a solution in Julia, not one that makes a direct change to which Windows application opens what file extension.